# How do I restore boot capability to replaced drive

Tags: boot

I have a machine with Ubuntu Server 12.04 that had 2 identical drives at installation (/dev/sda and /dev/sdb). A couple of software RAID1 arrays were created and everything was fine.

Now /dev/sdb failed.
I replaced the drive with another of the same capacity.
The machine booted and ran fine, but with the arrays degraded, of course.

This is what the partitions look like on /dev/sda:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                        bios_grub
 2      2097kB  502MB   500MB   linux-swap(v1)
 3      502MB   1001GB  1000GB                        raid
 4      1001GB  3001GB  2000GB                        raid
```

I have partitioned /dev/sdb identically (down to the sectors):

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name     Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                  primary  bios_grub
 2      2097kB  502MB   500MB   linux-swap(v1)  primary
 3      502MB   1001GB  1000GB                  primary  raid
 4      1001GB  3001GB  2000GB                  primary  raid
```

I have resilvered the arrays, took care of the swap.
I have issued: `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`

**My question is:** Is this enough to restore boot capability to /dev/sdb?
In case /dev/sda fails and is removed, will the machine boot from /dev/sdb?